# horizontally align elements in material design

Tags: css, material-design

I have a simple toolbar with two components: an h1 and a menu button.  I would like the h1 centered in the toolbar and the menu button on the left.  after playing around with the material design attributes I still cannot achieve my end goal.  do I need to write custom css?  here is my index html as of now

```
<md-toolbar layout="row" layout-align='start center'>
            <md-button class="md-icon-button md-primary" aria-label="Settings" flex='10'>
                <i class='material-icons md-36 md-light'>menu</i>
            </md-button>
            <h1 class='title' flex='90'>MusiComp</h1>
        </md-toolbar>
```

Comment: There is no flexbox method (or other CSS layout for that matter) that will center an element but ignore the size of another element **except for absolute positioning**. You would have to absolutely position the button so that it's size is ignored by the `h1`..which can then be 100% wide.

Comment: that's what I expected, but wasn't sure if there was a new, creative way to accomplish this.  Thank you, Paulie.

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with `<div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>`. Try adding this right before your `<h1 class='title' flex='90'>MusiComp</h1>`